# Javascript button click change / create PHP variable on same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cookies

I have searched stackoverflow for the past hour and have found similar questions but attempting the solution has given me only errors - it may be as I am trying to load it on the same page.

I have tried saving the value to a cookie in JS then loading it in php, also attempted through ajax, etc.

From what I've read it can't just be done within as PHP is server side and Javascript is browser side which I get.

I currently have a .html page with a form that sends values through POST:

**form.html**

```
<form id="calc" form name="calculator" method="post" action="/calculate.php">
```

The solution is not with the form, I can't have hidden fields as I need to user input. I could have a radio box in the form yes and then get the value that way, but that's not my question. My question is how I can get the user's input and turn it into php on the page the form redirects to calculate.php:

**calculate.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $x= $_POST['value']; 

echo "your something:";
echo $x;
?>

Click button below for option one to do this, or click two for that, or three for something else...
<button id="one"> one </button>

<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#one").click(function() {
            make php value 1
});
</script>

use php value from click
```

So the user will already have clicked submit. Then be redirected onto the .php page with their inputs, they can then choose button 1, 2 or 3 for example through javascript on calculate.php **NOT** the form.

My problem is I need to know on the same page - calculate.php, which button has been clicked in php. So that I can use their input and do different things with it depending on which button.

Is it possible to get a value to be set or create one from a button click on calculate.php itself with the javascript button producing a php value on the same page? Does it need to be loaded from an external.php page through ajax? Is there any other way?

Comment: You don't need javascript, just put a hidden input into your form receiving $value and your iteration code to value before form. Every time you submit, you will add 1.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre I have edited my code example as I don't think I explained it properly, the user will already have clicked submit. Then on the page they are on the can choose button 1, 2 or 3 through javascript. I need to know on the same page which buttons clicked in php.

Comment: Are the buttons with `1`, `2`, and `3` on `.form.html` or `calculate.php`? If they are on the form, you can simply make them radio buttons and pass the value in `$_POST`. If they're on `calculate.php`, the form should have nothing to do with the problem at all, as you would simply calculate the clicks in JavaScript and turn those variables into PHP variables.

Comment: One more time, I would put sole responsibility  into php.

Change button for checkbox/radio and each checkbox will have a name that you can capture in php after click. With you want so hard javascript, put hidden inputs with the names you want and, when you click into button, put the value into hidden respective input and submit after that with $('form').submit();

Comment: @Obsidian Age the form has nothing to do with the problem at all I just don't want people thinking the solution is in the form, "simply calculate the clicks in JavaScript and turn those variables into PHP variables. " this is exactly what I need can you elaborate hows the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Option:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $x= (isset($_POST['one'])) ? $_POST['one'] : '';
    $y = (isset($_POST['two'])) ? $_POST['two'] : '';
    $z = (isset($_POST['three'])) ? $_POST['three'] : ''; 

echo "your something:";
echo $x;
echo $y;
echo $z;
?>

<form name="calculator" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="one" VALUE="1"> ONE
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="two" VALUE="2"> TWO
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="three" VALUE="3"> THREE
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS mode:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $value= (isset($_POST['value'])) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
    $previous = (isset($_POST['previous'])) ? $_POST['previous'] : '';
    //play with value and previous one
     $x = //your algorithm;

echo "your something:";
echo $x;
?>

<form name="calculator" method="post">
<button type="button" value='1'>ONE</button>
<button type="button" value='2'>TWO</button>
<button type="button" value='3'>THREE</button>
<input name='value' type='hidden' value=''>
<input name='previous' type='hidden' value='<?= (isset($x)) ? $x : ''?>'>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $('input[name=value]').val($(this).val());
            $('form').submit();
});
</script>

use php value from click
```

Comment: When button is clicked it will lose all the values from the first form that was submitted? Notice: Undefined variable: $x

Comment: Do You want to store all values clicked before? Look, i put a example here, you will put this code wherever you want to improve your arquiteture, because it's a bad practice mess js html and php into same code, etc. It's just a example.

Comment: Yes I want all values still, so for example the user has inputed their X and Y and then I have calculated their Z value from the first from. I want to keep all values including $Z then I want to echo $Z. Then I want 3 buttons button one will do A to $Z, button two will do B to $Z and then button three will do C to $Z. So I need to store 1, 2, 3 as a php variable from which button has been clicked, and not lose all my data.

Comment: An input type to store your previous value

<input type='hidden' name='current' value='<?= (isset($_POST['z']) ? $_POST['z'] : '' ?>'>

Comment: I got errors, I have a lot of calculations and variables on the form not just Z, is there another way to do this? As ideally I'd prefer not to have to submit all values and recalculate.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A calculator? You're telling more complexity than your initial answer.